What actually is an augmented matrix, and why do they work?
I'm finishing a course in applied linear algebra and realized I don't understand how we can augment matrices and why it works. I know their uses and have no issue with Gaussian elimination, finding inverse matrices, etc. My professor has only really talked about techniques for computation rather than the actual theory and proofs.
When we take a system of equations such as
$$\begin{align*}
 2x_1 + 4x_2 -3x_3 &= 0 \\
3x_1 + x_2 &= 1 \\
x_1 +2x_2 - 2x_3 &= 4
\end{align*} $$
It is my understanding that we take the coefficient matrix:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & -3 \\
3 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And we augment it with the ride side of the equation:
$$
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 & 4 & -3 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & -2 & 4
\end{array}
$$
But how do these work? Can we perform any manipulation of these matrices? For example, can we subtract all $x_1$ terms to the other side and write the matrix as follows?
$$
\begin{array}{rr|rr}
4 & -3 & 0 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
2 & -2 & 4 & -1\\
\end{array}
$$
If we can do this, what happens if we perform Gaussian Elimination? What does the resulting matrix represent?
On top of this, I don't understand why or what is actually happening when we augment a matrix with $\Bbb I$ to find the inverse. If we were to express a matrix as a linear equation, what would augmented with $\Bbb I$ look like?

You might find my YouTube lecture — and following ones — helpful.

Your manipulation to reorder the $(2,3,1)$ column and negate it are column operations, not the row operations in Gaussian Elimination.

After Gaussian elimination one still has to interpret the results. For your
$$\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
4 & -3 & 0 & -2 \
1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \
2 & -2 & 4 & -1\
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{37}{14} \
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{20}7 \
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac5{14}\
\end{array}\right]
$$
From row 3, one may still find $x_1$ from $0=1-\frac5{14}x_1$, then finding $x_2,x_3$ would be less direct.

For $n\times n$ matrix $A$, performing Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix $\left[A\mid I_n\right]$ means solving $n$ systems of linear equations: $A \mathbf x_i = \mathbf e_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Here, $\mathbf e_i$ is all zero, except the $i$th component that equals $1$.

$x_1+2x_2−2x_3 =4$
$3x_1+x_2 +0x_3   =1$
$2x_1+4x_2−3x_3  =0  $
These are the three equations you gave in your question, just rearranged. If you were to solve these you might start by subtracting 2 times equation 1 from equation 3 giving: (You've probably had to do this in the past)
$x_1+2x_2−2x_3=4$
$3x_1+x_2 +0x_3   =1$
$0x_1+0x_2+x_3  =-8 $
This is exactly the same operation you do with an augmented matrix, the only difference is that instead of writing the arguments each time you just put all the $x_1$s in one column. You know that any number in that column represents the same number of $x_1$s in the original equation.
All this does is save time. When you are dealing with a very large number of simultaneous equations in many unknowns it saves a lot of time. The equations are also easier to deal with in matrix form. There are many programs available for you to simply enter the unknowns in in matrix form and they compute the answer for you. What's not to like about that?
You leave the constants on one side in the augmented matrix simply because you may have to apply the same equations to different initial conditions. All you have to do is change that one column of the augmented matrix. There is no benefit, and in fact increased difficulty if you put one column of the unknowns over on the right side.
Any allowed manipulation of the matrix is reversible. If I subtract two times row one from row three, I simply add two times column one to the new row three to get back to the original.
Say I start with matrix A on the left side and the identity matrix on the right side as an augmented matrix. Each step I take to reduce A to the identity matrix changes the identity matrix on the right into a new matrix, call it B. So, if I want to change B back to the identity matrix I have to take the opposite (inverse) steps that I took originally. This is why matrix B has become the inverse of matrix A.
